# Change Element Class From Another PHP Page With JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add an error reporting box using Bootstrap-4.

The Alert loads with the class of 'collapse' on the registration page:

```
<input type="text" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" name="username" 
placeholder="Username" required minlength="4" autofocus>
            <div id=error_message class=collapse>
              <span class="alert alert-danger"> <STRONG>Error:</STRONG><? 
$_SESSION['message'] ?>
            </span>
```

The form handler is here with a placeholder for code, as a separate PHP file.

```
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

//Test to see if username exists
if ($num != 0 ){
$_SESSION['message']="The username is already taken";
//JQUERY HERE TO SHOW BOOTSTRAP ALERT DIV - CLASS TO 'SHOW'
}
?>
```

It it possible, or indeed wise to get JQuery to affect the class on another page, or am I looking at this wrong way?  Apologies I'm a rank amateur and I'm very new to this.

Comment: Are you submitting via a form submit, or ajax?

Comment: Form submit, by Post. There's no AJAX being used.

Comment: Ok, so is PHP building the resulting page, I take it?

Comment: Yes, all PHP in this case.

Comment: Ok, so your PHP could conditionally not put the collapse class on the element, if there is an error, no?

Comment: Yes, if that makes more sense, if you mean that the class is removed on an error event (such as the MYSQL  returns! 0) unless I'm being slow to understand which is quite possible.

Comment: Right.  Just like you are using the session variable to put the message on the response page, you could check if that variable is set or not.  And only put the collapse class on the element if it is not set.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with bootstrap validation with remote file. For reference go through https://formvalidation.io/guide/validators/remote/